# Saving images names with their sizes to a file in Windows

Tags: windows, excel, image, text, save

In Windows, I have a folder `ImageDir` with images inside it. I want to save all the images names with their sizes in a text file or excel file.

How could I achieve this?

Comment: Did my solution work for you?

Comment: yup it worked thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you can try something very simple:

Open the cmd (<kbd>Winkey</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> `->` cmd <kbd>Enter</kbd>).
`cd` to the `ImageDir` directory. (I.e. something like `cd C:/users/folder/ImageDir`)
Enter `dir > my_text_file.txt` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Now you will have the complete output of the `dir` command in that directory, which includes the size and names of your images.

Edit: if you want **only** the file names and sizes, then instead of `dir > my_text_file.txt` use:

```
(for %F in (*) do @echo %F     %~zF) > my_text_file.txt
```